# What are the chances that the contraceptive pill will cause death of human zygote?

Tags: human-biology, embryology

The preventative pill, as I understand it, can cause zygotes to fail to attach to the uterine wall, or pry them off of it.

Ignoring any and all ethical implications, what are the chances that this will occur, provided the woman in question has taken the pill regularly preceding sexual intercourse, comparing with and without barrier method as well, the latter taking into account if it fails.

Comment: You should know that there is controversy on when to even define the beginning of pregnancy, therefore there is a really big assumption (and a lot of politics, whether or not you realize or intend that) in your statement "assuming that this qualifies as abortion." I would suggest rewriting your question to "what is the probability that preventative contraceptive pills will interfere with attachment of a zygote to the uterine wall?"

Comment: @BryanKrause Done.

Comment: Second comment, which I missed at first glance, is in your second paragraph: Why are you referring to a barrier method? I mean, if fertilization doesn't occur (due to a hormone pill or any other method) it doesn't make biological sense to even evaluate the question.

Comment: Which pill? What dosage? All barrier methods? Does that include 'soft' barriers like foam and gel? If you don't know what I'm getting at, it's: this is way too broad, unclear, and shows no research whatsoever.